# Setting default font size with fontconfig

Tags: fontconfig

I want to replace every font with a monospace font, which already works. However, I could not figure out how to specify a default font size. Here is my configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "urn:fontconfig:fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <alias>
        <family>serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Fira Code</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
    <alias>
        <family>sans-serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Fira Code</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
    <alias>
        <family>monospace</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Fira Code</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A while back I had the same problem, and after scouring the documentation this is what I put together (the `<match>` stuff is the relevant part).

My fonts.conf:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
    <match>
        <edit name="pixelsize"><double>9</double></edit>
    </match>
    <alias>
        <family>serif</family>
        <prefer><family>monospace</family></prefer>
    </alias>
    <alias>
        <family>sans-serif</family>
        <prefer><family>monospace</family></prefer>
    </alias>
    <alias>
        <family>sans</family>
        <prefer><family>monospace</family></prefer>
    </alias>
    <alias>
        <family>monospace</family>
        <prefer><family>tewi</family></prefer>
    </alias>
</fontconfig>
```